# Passing variable from onCreate() to onPause()

Tags: android, scoping

I have a variable `storyID` that I have successfully set in `onCreate`. But when I try to access it in `onPause` it returns `0`.

I presume this is a scoping issue, but can't see where I'm going wrong?

```
public class StoryBodyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView storyBodyTextView;
    private ScrollView storyBodyScrollView;
    public int storyID;
    Parcelable state;
    int scrollY;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_story_body, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_body);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        String story = extras.getString("story");
        int storyID = extras.getInt("story_id");
        Log.i("stories", Integer.toString(storyID));

        // show back arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        setTitle(story);

        storyBodyTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body_text_view);
        storyBodyScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.story_body_scroll_view);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        String storyBody = db.getStoryBody(storyID);

        storyBodyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(storyBody));

        if(state != null) {
            Log.d("pause", "trying to restore textview state..");
            storyBodyTextView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        }

        int scroll = storyBodyScrollView.getScrollY();
        Log.i("scroll", Integer.toString(scroll));

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Log.d("pause", "saving listview state @ onPause");
        // state = storyBodyTextView.onSaveInstanceState();
        scrollY = storyBodyScrollView.getScrollY();
        // Log.i("scroll", Integer.toString(scrollY));
        Log.i("insert", Integer.toString(storyID));
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        db.saveScrollPosition(scrollY, storyID);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `int` from `int storyID` in the `onCreate` method

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. Would you mind explaining why that was the problem?

Comment: You are creating a local variable inside 'OnCreate()', this means you are assigning new value to a local variable, and a global one is not updating.  Within 'OnPause()' you are using global variable, which is still untouched.